Lipschitz continuous pseudo gradient flow
Im currently looking at a proof of a deformation lemma for functionals on Banach spaces from "Linking Methods in Critical Point Theory" from Schechter. The situation is as follows, $G \in C^1(E) $ is our functional and $Y : \overline{E} \rightarrow E$ is a pseudo gradient field for $G$. Here $\overline{E}$ are the regular values of $G$. Then for a certain $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\delta > 0$ one looks at a function $\eta$ with
$$
Q_0 = \{u \in E : \vert G(u) - a \vert \leq 2 \delta\}\\
Q_1 = \{u \in E : \vert G(u) - a \vert \leq  \delta\}\\
Q_2 = E \backslash Q_0\\
\eta(u) = d(u,Q_2)/(d(u,Q_1) + d(u,Q_2))
$$
Such a function is well known to be Lipschitz continuous and basically looks like
$\eta(u) = 1 $ on $  Q_1$ and $\eta(u) = 0 $ on $  Q_2$ while being Lipschitz in-between.
Now we define a new function $W$ by
$$W(u) = - \eta(u)Y(u)$$
Now this is where things get weird. The book now states that this function is well defined and Lipschitz continuous on whole $E$. Is this possible?
As far as I understand such a pseudo gradient field cannot be continuously extended to whole $E$ and it's additionally also not guaranteed that $\eta$ vanishes near critical points of $G$. Is there something I am missing?

I solved this. Overlooked an additional hidden assumption which ensures that $\Vert G'(u)\Vert > 3 \epsilon$ whenever $u \in \{u \in E: \vert G(u) -a \vert > 3 \delta\}$ Hence all problem disappear as outside of this $\eta$ vanishes
